# What is the Card type of "Emblem Sorin, Lord of Innistrad"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-emblems

What is the Card type of "[Emblem Sorin, Lord of Innistrad](http://www.mtgmintcard.com/emblem-sorin-lord-innistrad-p-307101.html)"?

[mtgmint](http://www.mtgmintcard.com/emblem-sorin-lord-innistrad-p-307101.html) lists it as Creature but I am not 100% certain.

[image: Emblem Sorin, Lord of Innistrad]

Comment: In addition to the proper answers below, I should note that mtgmint probably lists it as a creature because it's the first non-creature 'token' to appear in that particular slot in a pack.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**It's not a real card. It's basically a token.**

As a game object, it's an "emblem".

The relevant comp rules:

> 113.1. Some effects put emblems into the command zone. An emblem is a marker used to represent an object that has one or more abilities, but
>   no other characteristics.
>
> 113.3. An emblem has no characteristics other than the abilities defined by the effect that created it. In particular, an emblem has no
>   name, no types, no mana cost, no color, and no expansion symbol.
>
> 113.5. An emblem is neither a card nor a permanent. Emblem isn't a card type.

[Sorin, Lord of Innistrad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249985) has an ability that creates these things (yes, multiples will stack). Dark Ascension booster packs contain an emblem token thingy to help you keep track of it. You aren't obligated to use the emblem card, just like you aren't obligated to use the official token cards to represent tokens.

Answer (score 4):

The type is Emblem, more info on Emblems is available [here](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Emblem). This particular emblem can be created by [Sorin, Lord of Innistrad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSorin%2c%20Lord%20of%20Innistrad%5d). Basically, an emblem is a reminder of an effect. So far, there are no ways to interact with emblems once they are created.